# How to loop a nested ruleset in less?

Tags: css, less

I am trying to `each` a nested ruleset in less, because it makes my code clear.
Like this:

```less
@m-button-sizes:
    x-large;

@m-button-sizes-rules: {
    @x-large: {
        height: 50px;
        padding: 15px 25px;
    }
};



.box {
    each(@m-button-sizes, {
        @x: @m-button-sizes-rules[@@value];

        .test {
            @x();
        }

    })
}
```

But I feel the `@m-button-sizes` was repetitive. Is there any way to remove it?
I've also tried doing something, but failed(like this).

```less
@m-button-sizes-rules: {
    @x-large: {
        height: 50px;
        padding: 15px 25px;
    }
};


.box {
    each(@m-button-sizes-rules, {
        @x: @m-button-sizes-rules[@key];

        .test {
            @x();
        }

    })
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use `.@{key}` and `@value()` syntax

```
.box {
    each(@m-button-sizes-rules, {
        .@{key} {
            @value();
        }
    })
}
```